# Age field in database off by one

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Take [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58346/members-by-age-and-reputation) for example. And checking the "real" user profiles, the ages are all either off by one, or nonexistent. This might make sense since the data doesn't arrive constantly, except everybody is listed in the database a year *older* than they actually are... can this be fixed?

Comment: I think it's more likely that they're listed as the age that they'll turn at some point in the current year, but I'm not sure whether or not that's intentional.