# Data on data.stackexchange.com is seriously flawed

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Age calculations are wrong in the data dump export](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/age-calculations-are-wrong-in-the-data-dump-export)
> [Age field in database off by one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/age-field-in-database-off-by-one)

I was messing around a bit and then I did this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63363/wtf

Compare that with my real profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/565635/nightcracker

The weird part is is that my reputation is incorrect (this is most likely the case because it doesn't get updated too often), but the really worrying part is that my age is incorrect!

This must be an error somewhere, because I have entered my birthdate as 13/11/1994, which obviously means my age is 17 (and this actually does get shown on my SO profile).

So what's up here?

Comment: +1 for saying that your age being off by one is a "serious flaw" =)

Comment: I see your problem: the code doesn't account for 13 months in the Netherlands!  :-P  (This is why I prefer using `date '+%Y_%m_%d'`.)

Answer (score 3):

The Data Explorer is not updated immediately. The data you're seeing there is from **February 1st**. If you visit the [homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you can see all the sites and all the way to the right it lists a date with the phrase "most recent" below it. That's the date from which the data is current.

As for the age, most likely a bug. It's probably only calculating `current year - birth year` to come up with the value of 18. When I run the query for my user ID, it says I'm 21 even though my birthdate is April 8, 1991.

Comment: Even on February 1st I was born on 13/11/1994 :P

Comment: @nightcracker: The first paragraph only relates to the reputation.