# 'Age' field in data explorer is inconsistent with main site

Tags: bug, data-explorer, age

This appears to be a re-occurrence (or it never was fixed) of this bug:

> **[Age calculations are wrong in the data dump export](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/age-calculations-are-wrong-in-the-data-dump-export)**

Basically, when running a Data.SE query, the age field seems to be always off by one, [for example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111021/age-off-by-one-error?opt.textResults=true):

```
select 
   id as [User Link],
   age
from Users
Where 
    displayname like 'Richard J. Ross III'
```

---

```
User Link           age 
------------------- --- 
Richard J. Ross III 17
```

I'm not 17 yet, my birthday happens to be in September, and it makes [calculations like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178336/top-users-who-aged-in-teen-or-less/178337#178337) almost impossible.

Can we get this re-fixed, or at least have an explanation for this discrepancy?

Comment: Please don't close this as a dupe of the linked question. Anna [told me to re-post this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/age-calculations-are-wrong-in-the-data-dump-export?noredirect=1#comment538855_41519).

Comment: Do you mean you resent your age being rounded up? Don't worry, a few years from now you won't even notice this :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no resentment is to be had here. It's just another bug that should be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, hm. See my comment on [this duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/age-field-in-database-off-by-one) (which I'm not casting a vote on this post for, since it itself was incorrectly closed, sigh...). I'd speculate that it has something to do with guessing birthdates, but I'm not sure that makes sense (and isn't easy to do some other way).

Comment: Caching. Always caching.

Comment: @Knights usually I'd agree with you, but if that bug was fixed 3 years ago then I should have never been 17 in their database at all. Obviously it's a bug unrelated to caching.

Comment: To be honest, that was sarcasm. But, more seriously, are you older than 16.5 years?

Comment: @Knights Indeed I am, my birthday is September 29th, making me 16.583 years old. However, age is something that probably shouldn't be rounded.

Comment: Indeed, however, rounding is probably what's happening here. Try me - do I show up 16 or 17?

Comment: @Knights You also appear as 17 in the explorer: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/111035?UserId=1131435

Comment: Then they're very likely rounding instead of flooring.

Comment: This bug report is no longer relevant since birthday, and age, have been hard deleted in the database level.